# Swift 2/ Parse If PFUser id is the same in Likes Class

Tags: swift, parse-platform, swift2, pfuser

I'm building an app which has the following classes

- **Users**

objectId

username

- **Recipes**

ObjectId

Recipe Name

Recipe File

UploadedByUser(Pointer to class Users)

- **Likes**

LikedByUser(Pointer to class Users)

LikedRecipe(Pointer to class Recipes)

So if a user has already liked one recipe, the image of the button inside the cell should have a specific BackgroundImage, and if is not should have a different one. What i've tried is this

```
let likesClassy = PFObject(className: LIKES_CLASS_NAME)
let currentUser = PFUser.currentUser()

if likesClassy[LIKES_LIKED_BY] === currentUser! {
    let imgLiked = UIImage(named: "likedButt") as UIImage!
    cell.likeOutlet.setBackgroundImage(imgLiked, forState: UIControlState.Normal)


} else {

    let imgUnLiked = UIImage(named: "likeButt") as UIImage!
    cell.likeOutlet.setBackgroundImage(imgUnLiked, forState: UIControlState.Normal)

}
```

And i have this code inside the collectionView where i load also how many likes the recipe has etc. 
I attach you the image from the parse.com class below

So in the `if` statement i'm trying to say that if the current user is equal with the userpointer of the Likes class, then the background image of the button should be likedButt, else should be likeButt.

But this doesnt work and i cant figure out why.
Any idea?

Update. I attach you the full likes class

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't fetch objects in Parse server. You should fetch the objects with some predicate options. This is the function you should use. It looks the your currentUser and your LIKES_LIKED_BY row in your Parse. If your LIKES_LIKED_BY row has a currentUser it fetches users.

```
    func getLikedUsers() {
    let user = PFUser.currentUser()
    let query = PFQuery(className: "LIKES_CLASS_NAME")
    query.whereKey("LIKES_LIKED_BY", equalTo: user!)
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock() {
        (let fetchedObjects, error) in
        if error == nil {
            // Query succeed.
            if fetchedObjects?.isEmpty == false {
                //If your currentUser already liked.
                if let fetchedUsers = fetchedObjects as? [PFUser] {
                    for fetchedUser in fetchedUsers {
                        print(fetchedUser.username)
                        // You got the users Do someting with your liked users.
                    }
                }
            } else {
                // Your user didn't liked
            }
        } else {
            // Parse Query fail. Do someting with error.
            print(error?.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share your class and Parse database picture. I think you didn't fetch objects.

Comment: I updated with the images but you think that i have to make a full query at this class `Likes` and then change the button image?

Comment: I should put this outside of the collectionView ?

Comment: I don't know what will you do with likedUsers, anyway you should not put the query codes in your collectionView methods. If you want to just try, just copy and paste the codes in your collectionView.